# First name validation using html 5 pattern

Tags: html, validation, design-patterns

I have this code

```
 echo '<input type="text" maxlength="32" name="first_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]" value="'.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].'" required>';
```

Even if I put something correct it says 'PLease match the requested format'

The data is 'testme' which is correct but it's not passing the validation.

Comment: Do not `echo` HTML, not in 2014. Use any templating system out there [Twig, Handlebars, whatever].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify how long the pattern should be. `pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,32}"`

```
echo '<input type="text" maxlength="32" name="first_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,32}" value="'.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].'" required>';
```

Comment: Sorry once again as it was my mistake.Now it is working.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`pattern="[A-Za-z ]{1,32}"` <- Use space in the first name pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For the data 'testme' (it has 6 characters)

`echo '<input type="text" maxlength="32" name="first_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{6}" value="'.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].'" required>';`

or else you can give a pattern with a range

`echo '<input type="text" maxlength="32" name="first_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,255}" value="'.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].'" required>';`

in this case you can input 1 to 255 characters as input value